# Bug in the modified time?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

When sorting the questions by `Active` I see [this question](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/546/should-restriction-geography-questions-be-duplicates) about 5th with last activity 12 hours ago by Daniel Bingham.  Yet if i look at the question there are comments 2 hours ago by Aaronut.  why is it not bubbling up the active when people are posting comments to the answers?  or is that not how it works?

Answer (score 1):

Comments do not count as activity. Activity occurs when the question is edited, or new answers are given.

Comment: bah! thanks....